# The data length obtained by socket read/recv is uncertain

Tags: linux, sockets, unix

In TCP connection(SOCK_STREAM ，BLOCK socket), the send() interface sends 2726 bytes of data, and the receiver uses read(fd, *recv_buf, 10240) to receive data. The problem is that sometimes the length of data returned by read() is 2726 bytes, sometimes 1448 bytes and 1278 bytes are returned successively (that is, the data amount of the sending is received **TWICE**).
Can the return value of read() be predicted in this case? We expect the read() to return all 2726 bytes of data at one time, and can recv() with MSG_WAITALL solve this problem?

Comment: Your expectation is incorrect. TCP is a streaming protocol so it has no concept of application level msg boundaries. The TCP receiver stack has no idea that your app expects to receive exactly `2726` bytes. It is up to your application code to determine the boundaries. You could use `MSG_WAITALL` but you would need to know exactly how much the sender is sending each time which is impractical.

Comment: You need to explicitly define the boundaries of your TCP messages at the application level. Either 1) send a message's length before sending its data, or 2) terminate each message with a unique delimiter that never appears in the message data. The receiver can then 1) read the length and then read the specified number of bytes, or 2) read until the delimiter arrives.